# Фильтр по категориям в Django

Tags: python, django, ecommerce

К примеру, у меня в магазине есть категории товаров [ссылка](http://joxi.ru/5mdvGpzukaGYjA) 
В каждой категории - однотипные товары, с похожими характеристиками.
В каждой категории - фильтр под эти характеристики.
То есть у материнских плат одни свойства, у процессоров другие.
И выходит так, что под каждую категорию, нужно заводить отдельное приложение
так как в разных категориях у товаров разные свойства.
И помимо отдельных приложений, получается ещё вот такая каша
[ссылка](http://joxi.ru/DrlbEPzhvGlky2) 
Так как под каждое свойство, нужно заводить модель. Свойства нужно редактировать.
То есть, если у меня 5-6 категорий, то нужно создавать столько же приложений
немного сумбурно как по мне. Кажется что это проблема архитектуры, но как её избежать - вопрос.

Comment: Возможно это вам поможет. Django mptt
https://django-mptt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/